# Using Mutex and lock_guard with a vector in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am a newbie in Threading in C++. I need your help regarding usage of `mutex` and `lock_guard` (this part doesn't matter). I have a main function and a secondary functions.

Please tell me why multithreading doesn't work when I add `lock_guard(mtx)`;
When I remove it, it runs faster but wrongly. Can you help me with it?

I need a correct access to the vector `vec` and enabling threading.

```
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

std::mutex mtx;

void threadCall(std::vector<int> &vec, int start, int end){
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mtx);
    for(int i=start; i<end; i++)
      vec[i] = i;
}

void ThreadFunc(std::vector<int> vec){
    std::vector<std::thread> threads(2);
    threads[0] = std::thread(&threadCall, std::ref(vec), 0, 10);
    threads[1] = std::thread(&threadCall, std::ref(vec), 10, 20);

    threads[0].join();
    threads[1].join();
}

int main(){

    std::vector<int> vec(20);
    ThreadFunc(vec);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are aware, I hope, that you are passing an empty vector, by copy.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it, Please avoid typos, but the main question is thread failure ) when mutex used.

Comment: No. You avoid typos, so people won't chase their tail trying to help you.

Comment: Your code fails with or without synchronization or threads because you are accessing items of empty vector out of bounds at this line `vec[i] = i;`. You need to insert those items first.

Comment: _"Please tell me why multithreading doesn't work"_ Define _doesn't work_. _"When I remove it, it runs faster but wrongly"_ Define _wrongly_. How did 4 people think this was worthy of upvoting?

Comment: Your mutex serializes the execution of threads. As both threads lock the same mutex, one wins and the other has to wait until the former is done. This needs the same time than doing work without threads + thread overhead.

Comment: doesnt work means, it is slow as one thread in Ubuntu.

Comment: - Scheff, that's what I need to fix. How can I find a solution?

Comment: @VTT right, or to `resize()` so that there are at least empty elements there that can be indexed and assigned to. That and what StoryTeller pointed out are fundamentals, indicating that there are more basic problems here than threading.

Comment: E.g. moving the guard inside the loop to make the critical section shorter. However, multi-threading works better with less communication overhead. Copying the vector before starting the threads, so that each thread has its "private" copy would make locking unnecessary and provide speed-up.

Comment: Your threads _do_ get copies actually though probably unintentional. (Hence locking wouldn't be necessary.) `void threadCall(std::vector<int> vec, ...)` copies the 1st argument. If you want to pass by reference you have to change to `threadCall(std::vector<int> &vec, ...)`. Notice the ampersand (&) which makes the difference.

Answer (score 5):

The mutex is preventing the threads from doing any work in parallel. As long as you can guarantee that each thread is not going to write to the same part of the vector you don't need the mutex at all.

The other problem is you are passing your vector by value. You should instead pass by reference:

```
void threadCall(std::vector<int>& vec, int start, int end){
    for(int i=start; i<end; i++)
      vec[i] = i;
}

void ThreadFunc(std::vector<int>& vec){
    std::vector<std::thread> threads(2);
    threads[0] = std::thread(&threadCall, std::ref(vec), 0, 10);
    threads[1] = std::thread(&threadCall, std::ref(vec), 10, 20);

    threads[0].join();
    threads[1].join();
}

int main(){
    std::vector<int> vec(20);
    ThreadFunc(vec);
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dbLu2iRWeKktxnOG).

Comment: Thanks Chris, but I can't guarantee "each thread is not going to write to the same part of the vector".

Comment: @Huseyn Rahimov If that is the case, and the only work each thread is doing is writing to the vector then you can't really make it run in parallel.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but there should be a sophisticated way to to do that.

Comment: If multiple threads are writing to the same part of the vector, what result do you expect? The result will be effectively random depending on which thread writes last.

Comment: I suggest you write a question with code closer to your real problem.

Answer (score 5):

To start with, stop passing the vector by value, pass references. After that is resolved, your particular example doesn't need a mutex at all, actually. Your vector has a fixed size:

```
std::vector<int> vec(20);
```

And all elements are default constructed from the get go. Since all you do is assignment:

```
vec[i] = i;
```

The vector won't reallocate any storage or adjust its item count. So there's no need to lock access to the vector as a whole. Couple that with the fact that each thread operates on a separate sub-range, and there aren't any data races present. You don't need synchronization primitives.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that mutex is taken by the first thread and second thread can't work until it's released.

So, essentially you receive a multi-threaded application that where all threads do their job serially.

You can move your guard into for-loop

```
for(int i=start; i<end; i++) {
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mtx);
  vec[i] = i;
}
```

That will give threads a possibility to work together over the passed vector.

**BUT:**

You need to take into account that multiple threads not always give a performance boost jut because **concurrency != parallelism**.

I would expect from this application in this way be actually slower than a single-threaded implementation because the following:

1. Threads are blocking each other by a `mutex` so only one thread runs at time
2. You spend time on context switch between threads

**SOLUTION IDEA:**

If you want to run it truly parallel, you need to make threads work on independent data and then join the result.

Comment: what is your solution?

Comment: @HuseynRahimov take a look on improved answer.

Comment: according to your solution (different data), is it faster when I still keep the mutex? Will mutex lock different data independently or again sequentially?

Comment: I tried it according to your solution (different data), but there is no difference.

Comment: @HuseynRahimov 1. In this case mutex is not needed at all. 2. How do you measure the performance? 3. Do you have a code?